How do I find $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cot 7h}{\cot 5h}$?
I am trying to find $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cot 7h}{\cot 5h}$$ without using L'Hopital's Rule (since that is introduced later in a text).
So far, using that
$$\cot (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\cot \alpha \cot \beta - 1}{\cot \alpha + \cot \beta}$$
I simplified to get
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\cot 7h}{\cot 5h} = \frac{ \frac{\cot 6h\cot h - 1}{\cot 6h + \cot h}}{\frac{\cot 6h \cot(-h)-1}{\cot 6h + \cot(-h)}} = \frac{\cot 6h\cot h - 1}{\cot 6h + \cot h} \cdot \frac{\cot 6h + \cot(-h)}{\cot 6h \cot(-h)-1}$$.
But, this just gives me
$$\frac{\cot 6h\cot h - 1}{\cot 6h + \cot h} \cdot \frac{\cot 6h - \cot h}{-\cot 6h \cot h-1}$$
I'm not sure if this is how one could go about finding the limit. If so, I don't know how to continue from the previous step.

Are you allowed to use sinus and cosinus.

@hamam_Abdallah: Yes, I am.

Can you use the well known limit $\lim_0\frac{\sin(H)}{H}=1$

@hamam_Abdallah: Yes

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cot{7h}}{\cot{5h}} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos{7h}\sin{5h}}{\cos{5h}\sin{7h}} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\cos{7h}\frac{\sin{5h}}{5h}}{\cos{5h}\frac{\sin{7h}}{7h}}\frac{5}{7} = \frac{1\cdot 1}{1\cdot 1}\frac{5}{7} =\frac{5}{7}  
$$
